# Loading a composer class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, packagist

I'm in the process of trying to make a laravel compatible composer/packagist package. I'm using Laravel 5.5.

I've created a package : `floor9design/machine-identifier`. Composer downloads this to `vendors/floor9design` fine, but despite reading/googling how to do this, I'm unsure of how to include this in my laravel projects.

PHP Storm is correctly picking up the class, auto-completing as expecting.

I have not modified any files so far. If I add the following to a controller:

`use Floor9design\MachineIdentifier\MachineIdentifier;`

(alongside some class usage on the page).

PHP storm autocompletes this (as it does with other classes validly called).

When I try to load this, the following error comes:

`Class 'Floor9design\MachineIdentifier\MachineIdentifier' not found`

I've had a look round plenty of tutorials, and this final step seems to be missing from a lot of information.

I realise there are three approaches:

Firstly:
Direct `include_once`, which while working, is not the normal approach

Secondly:
Pre-laravel 5.5 approach (add *something* to `app.php`)

Thirdly
Laravel 5.5 approach and up, autodetection of *something*.

I've deliberately said *something* as the documentation seems to speak about `ServiceProviders`, and I simply don't get how they work.

Let me rephrase this into a question and a follow up question:

Question: apart from `include_once`, how do I load the MachineIdentifer class from `floor9design/machine-identifier` in Laravel.

Question 2: If the answer is via a service provider, can you simply explain how they relate to one another.

Thanks

### Answer (as accepted below)

On the composer repo I was incorrectly specifying the PSR4 namespace, which is now corrected to:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Floor9design\\MachineIdentifier\\": "src"
    }
}
```

The previous namespace had a `-`, which is an illegal character. Many thanks to lawrence-cherone.

Comment: Thanks for the accept :), you might be intrested in stripping out some methods from this class, to cover all system infos: https://github.com/plinker-rpc/system/blob/master/src/System.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's good to know. I'll review these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PSR4 is wrong in the package

`floor9design\\machine-identifier\\": "src"`

Will cause the composer/autoload_psr4.php to map to:

```
'floor9design\\machine-identifier\\' => array($vendorDir . '/floor9design/machine-identifier/src'),
```

Which is not a valid class namespace.

You should change the PSR4 to match your class namespace:

`Floor9design\\MachineIdentifier\\": "src"`

Once you fix that you will be able to use it like normal from anywhere in your project.